# In Prolog, how can I create a list of lists when I am using a variable bound to several values?

Tags: list, loops, prolog, character-replacement

## Issue

I am trying to move all new lists that I create into one super list of lists. Instead the output is formatted as a bunch of individually changed lists.

The problem likely stems from the fact I use `between` to assign `Iterations` and `Size`, but I am not sure what else I can do.

#### Input

```
placeRedBlocks(4, X), loopReplace(X, Y), append([X], [Y], Z).
```

#### Expectation

```
Z = [[b, b, b, b], [r, r, r, b], [r, r, r, r], [b, r, r, r]]
```

#### Reality

```
X = [b, b, b, b],
Y = [r, r, r, b],
Z = [[b, b, b, b], [r, r, r, b]]
X = [b, b, b, b],
Y = [r, r, r, r],
Z = [[b, b, b, b], [r, r, r, r]]
X = [b, b, b, b],
Y = [b, r, r, r],
Z = [[b, b, b, b], [b, r, r, r]]
false
```

## Code Explanation

This prolog code takes a list of values and replaces the designated values and returns it into another list.

```
placeRedBlocks(Length, List) :-
    findall('b', between(1, Length, _), List).

replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):- 
  I > -1,
  NI is I-1,
  replace(T, NI, X, R), !.

replaceX(A,_,0,_,A):- !.
replaceX(Line,Index,NumElm,Elm,NLine) :-
  replace(Line,Index,Elm,BLine),
  Index1 is Index+1,
  NumElm1 is NumElm-1,
  replaceX(BLine,Index1,NumElm1,Elm,NLine).

loopReplace(ListToReplace, NewList) :-
    length(ListToReplace, Len),
    TotalCount is Len-3,
    between(0, TotalCount, Iterations),
    between(3, Len, Size),
    replaceX(ListToReplace, Iterations, Size, 'r', NewList).
```

In `replaceX`:

`Line` is the list you are trying to replace the values in. `Index` is the position in the list where you start replacing values. `NumElm` is the number of elements you are replacing in total. `Elm` is the character or number that replaces the other values in the list. `NLine` is the list where the output will go.

Comment: You say you are "trying to move all new lists that I create into one super list of lists". Then just use `findall/3`.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with `findall/3` and `bagof/3` I found an answer that works for my question.

#### Input

```
placeRedBlocks(7, X), findall(Y, loopReplace(X, Y), Z).
```

would get me

```
Z = [[r, r, r, b, b, b, b], [r, r, r, r, b, b, b], [r, r, r, r, r, b, b], [r, r, r, r, r, r, b], [r, r, r, r, r, r, r], [b, r, r, r, b, b, b], [b, r, r, r, r, b, b], [b, r, r, r, r, r, b], [b, r, r, r, r, r, r], [b, b, r, r, r, b, b], [b, b, r, r, r, r, b], [b, b, r, r, r, r, r], [b, b, b, r, r, r, b], [b, b, b, r, r, r, r], [b, b, b, b, r, r, r]]
```